# Need to translate into symbols "Someone in this class has done Data Structures”?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

The statements given are

1. There is someone in this class who has done Data Structures.
2. Everyone who does Knowledge Engineering does Data Structures.

my conclusion

$D=$ who does data structures

$K=$ knowledge engineering

my answer is

1. $∃x((D(x))$
2. $∀x((K(x) → D(x))$

Is my translation correct?
please help me with this one ?

Comment: I don't know if I am just reading too much into this, but note that we have the two statements of the form "$x$ has done Data Structures" and "$x$ does Data Structures" which are not the same. Also we have the statement "$x$ is in this class" of which I do not know if it was supposed to be used as well.

Comment: Assume that the *universe* is "this Class". Then YES: "There is someone in this class who has done Data Structures" will be $\exists x \ \text {DS}(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That sounds a lot like an answer to me. Spread out over two comments. Why did you choose to answer in the comment section rather than, I dunno, an _answer post_?

Answer (score 1):

Going off of what Mauro is saying, let's say that the universe is *not* the class. Since it is not the universe then let's say $C(x) = "x \text{ is in this class.}"$ Then:

$1)$ There is someone in this class who has done Data Structures.
$$\exists x (C(x) \land D(x))$$
**Reason:** If someone is in this class then they must also have done data structures. Someone is in this class and does something. There is someone in this class and has *not* taken data structues.

$2)$ Everyone who does Knowledge Engineering does Data Structures.

$$\forall x(K(x)\to D(x))$$

**Reason:** Everyone that has done knowledge engineering also does data structures. So if you're a knowledge engineer then you do data structures.